# Proxy function works with requests, but not with a chrome browser?

Tags: python

I have no idea why the following code returns the proxy as invalid only for the chrome browser help is appreciated. Below are the imports.

```
import requests
import json
import time
import random
import threading
from threading import Thread
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime
from proxymanager import ProxyManager
from random import randint
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def getProxy():
    try:
        proxy_manager = ProxyManager('proxies.txt')
        proxydict = proxy_manager.random_proxy()
        proxies = proxydict.get_dict()
    except:
        proxies = []
    return proxies

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=https://%s' %getProxy)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: Tried using http:// aswell

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out of a limb and guess the problem is with the proxy expansion - you're trying to pass a `dict` to Chrome instead of the actual proxy address. You want to get the actual value from the Proxy() class in your `getProxy()` function, e.g.:

```
def get_proxy(string_only=True):
    try:
        proxy_manager = ProxyManager("proxies.txt")
        proxy = proxy_manager.random_proxy() 
        if string_only:
            return proxy.proxy_string
        return proxy.get_dict()
    except (OSError, IOError, IndexError) as e: # couldn't load the file / file is empty
        return None

# With Chrome:
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = get_proxy()
if proxy:
    chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=" + proxy)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")

# with requests:
response = requests.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com", proxies=get_proxy(False))
# etc.
```

I'd also recommend to load the proxy list only once if you intend to call this function often and if the `proxies.txt` is a static file.

Comment: This seems to just be returning my IP, instead of the proxy

Comment: @JustACoder - Then your `proxies.txt` has defined your IP as a proxy, check its contents. You can always print/trace the `proxy` value before being passed to Chrome to make sure it picks the right one.

Comment: Why would it do this? (define my IP as a proxy)

Comment: Also proxy = get_proxy() is giving me an error which states Assiging to a function call which returns None

Comment: @JustACoder - Why would it define your address as a proxy, I don't know - I didn't create your `proxies.txt`. Are you sure it even gets loaded? As for the the error can you post a full trace of it?

Comment: That is the full error (it does not break the script), I have a proxy loaded into proxies.txt and when I print proxy it's returning None everytime do you know what is causing this?

Comment: @JustACoder - How are you executing your script, what interpreter are you using and where is `proxies.txt` relative to your script? If it's returning `None` that means that either the `proxies.txt` wasn't loaded (you can try to trace the exception capture) or that the contents of your `proxies.txt` does not match the required format by the `ProxyManager` package.

Comment: proxies.txt is in the same directory as the script, I am using windows powershell to execute the script, it should be formatted correctly for proxymanager as I believe it was working before.

Comment: Yeah, it's formatted as it should be stated in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/proxy-manager/0.0.6

Comment: @JustACoder - Ooops, I had a typo above - I forgot to return a valid proxy. Try with the updated `get_proxy()` function.

Comment: just encounted another error, when the file is empty it returns   File "tronio.py", line 28, in get_proxy
    return proxy_manager.random_proxy().proxy_string
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\proxymanager\manager.py", line 45, in random_proxy
    return random.choice(self.proxies)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\random.py", line 258, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Comment: @JustACoder - Just add `IndexError` to the catch-ignore list as above, although it should probably be handled within the ProxyManager class given that if you don't pass a file to it it will initiate a blank proxy to avoid errors such as this.

Comment: @JustACoder - Of course it doesn't, you didn't state you want it to work with both. Chrome expects a string so that's what the function provides, the `requests` module, on the other hand, expects a dictionary so for the `requests` module the `return` from the `get_proxy()` function should be: `return proxy_manager.random_proxy().get_dict()`. You can combine both in the same function and then have an argument passed to it to determine the return type you expect.

Comment: Alright thanks, @zwer I'm very new to python so if you could maybe help me write the argument to determine the return that'd be a great help!

Comment: @JustACoder - Check the above.

Comment: @JustACoder - Thread concurrency shouldn't affect the `get_proxy()` function as there are no persistent states that can be messed up in non-atomic calls. I'd reckon the problem is somewhere else and it's way out of scope of this question anyway.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, I had messed up defining the drivers causing them to spam open but I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
 def get_proxy():
        try:
            proxy_manager = ProxyManager("proxies.txt")
            return proxy_manager.random_proxy().proxy_string
        except (OSError, IOError) as e: # couldn't load the file
            return None

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    proxy = get_proxy()
    if proxy:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=" + proxy)
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```